# Visual Studio 2015 breaks HierarchyId CLR Type

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 preview an issue was introduced where the ToString() method on the hierarchyid throws a HierarchyException 24000 in SSMS

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "hierarchyid": 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24000: SqlHierarchyId operation failed because HierarchyId object was constructed from an invalid binary string. 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.GetBits(UInt16 startBit, UInt16 nBits, UInt64& bits)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.ExtractOrd(UInt16& bitOffset, UInt32 stage, Int64& ord)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.ExtractComponent(UInt16& bitOffset, SComponent& component, levelType& type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.ToString()
```

I couldn't find a solution for this!

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it sure does :-(

Already has been reported, and you are not the only one to reproduce it.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1063935/visual-studio-2015-breaks-hierarchyid-clr-type

Comment: Yes I know that it's reported, but I hoped there will be faster answer.

Comment: I expect digging through the files installed with VS2015 (search by date) you might be able to nuke it but you would want to uninstall, and then try cleaning out each remaining file